# Disambiguate template function specializations - value vs. reference

Tags: c++, templates, casting, c++17, pass-by-reference

This question requires a bit of context - *if you're feeling impatient, skip past the line break...* I have a `Vector-3,4` and `Matrix-3,4` library defined in terms of template specializations; i.e., `Vector<n>` and `Matrix<n>` are defined in `Matrix.hh`, while non-trivial implementations (e.g., matrix multiplication, matrix inverse) have explicit specializations or instantiations in `Matrix.cc` for `N = {3,4}`.

This approach has worked well. In theory, an app could instantiate a `Matrix<100>`, but couldn't multiply or invert the matrix, as there are no implementation templates visible in the header. Only `N = {3,4}` are instantiated in `Matrix.cc`

Recently, I've been adding **robust** methods to complement any operation that involves an inner product - including matrix multiplications, matrix transforms of vectors, etc. Most 3D transforms (projections / orientations) are relatively well-conditioned, and any minor precision errors are not a problem since shared vertices / edges yield a consistent rasterization.

There are some operations that *must* be numerically robust. I can't do anything about how a GPU does dot products and matrix operations when rendering; but I *cannot* have control / camera parameters choke on valid geometry - and inner products are notorious for pathological cancellation errors, so the robust methods use compensated summation, products, dot products, etc.

---

---

This works fine for, say, `Vector` inner product in `Matrix.hh` :

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// inner product:


template <int n> float
inner (const GL0::Vector<n> & v0, const GL0::Vector<n> & v1)
{
    float r = v0[0] * v1[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        r += v0[i] * v1[i];

    return r; // the running sum for the inner product.
}


float
robust_inner (const GL0::Vector<3> &, const GL0::Vector<3> &);

float
robust_inner (const GL0::Vector<4> &, const GL0::Vector<4> &);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The implementations in `Matrix.cc` are [not trivial](https://www.tuhh.de/ti3/paper/rump/OgRuOi05.pdf).

I'm in more dubious territory when adding a robust method for `[A]<-[A][B]` matrix multiplication; perhaps the naming is not ideal:

```
template <int n> GL0::Matrix<n> &
operator *= (GL0::Matrix<n> & m0, const GL0::Matrix<n> & m1);

// (external instantiation)


GL0::Matrix<3> &
robust_multiply (GL0::Matrix<3> &, const GL0::Matrix<3> &);

GL0::Matrix<4> &
robust_multiply (GL0::Matrix<4> &, const GL0::Matrix<4> &);
```

There *is* a `N = {3,4}` implementation for the `operator *=` in `Matrix.cc`, but it relies on the naive inner product and is not robust - though typically good enough for GL / visualization. The `robust_multiply` functions are also implemented in `Matrix.cc`.

Now of course, I want the `Matrix` multiplication operator:

```
template <int n> GL0::Matrix<n>
operator * (GL0::Matrix<n> m0, const GL0::Matrix<n> & m1) {
    return (m0 *= m1);
}
```

Leading me to the problematic definitions:

```
inline GL0::Matrix<3>
robust_multiply (GL0::Matrix<3> m0, const GL0::Matrix<3> & m1) {
    return robust_multiply(m0, m1);
}

inline GL0::Matrix<4>
robust_multiply (GL0::Matrix<4> m0, const GL0::Matrix<4> & m1) {
    return robust_multiply(m0, m1);
}
```

The call to `robust_multiply(m0, m1)` is *ambiguous*. ***Q: How can I force the LHS argument to be interpreted as a reference, ensuring a call to the previous function that modifies the (m0) argument.*** Obviously I can name `robust_multiply` as something else, but I'm more interested in utilizing the type system. I feel I'm missing something obvious in `<utility>` or `<functional>`. How do I force a call to the correct function?

---

*(Sorry about the word count - I'm trying to clarify my own thinking as I write)*

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but you can make two overloads: one taking `&` (lvalue reference, ~non-temporaries) and one taking `&&` (rvalue reference, ~temporaries), these are disjoint. Why exactly did you end up with two distinct implementations of `robust_multiply` for `Matrix<3>`? It does not make sense to me regardless of programming language used.

Comment: If `robust_multiply` is both `*` and `*=`, you can do `const&` in the first one and `&` in the second one.

Comment: @yeputons - I wanted `robust` functions that mirrored the separate `lhs *= rhs` and `lhs * rhs` semantics. I also fell into the trap of tunnel vision with naming, etc., and perhaps lost some perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named `robust_multiply` wrong.

`*=` and `*` are fundamentally different operations.  They are related, but not the same operation - different verbs.

Overloading should be used when you are doing the same operation on different nouns.

If you do that, then your problems almost certainly evaporate. Sensible overloads are easy to write.

In your case, you want to change between writing to an argument or not based on its l/r value category.  That leads to ambiguity problems.

I mean, there are workarounds to your problem -- use `std::ref` or pointers, for example, or `&`, `&&` and `const&` overloads -- but they are patches here.

Naming this in programming is hard.  And here is a case were you should do that hard bit.

...

Now one thing you could do is bless the arguments.

```
template<class T>
struct robust{
  T t;
  explicit operator T&()&{return t;}
  explicit operator T()&&{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
  }
  // also get() methods
  explicit robust(T&&tin):
    t(std::forward<T>(tin))
  {}
};
```

then override `*=` and `*` for robust wrapped matrices.

```
robust{a}*=b;
```

(have lhs must be robust to keep overload count down).

Now the verb is clear, I just dressed up the nouns.

But this is just an idea, and not use-tested.

Comment: Yeah - renaming *is* the correct approach. As you say, there are workarounds - but this is just a case of staring too long at the same code and not seeing the obvious issue - these are semantically different operations.

Comment: I just went with `robust_compose` for the `lhs *= rhs` form. However, this whole thing has forced me to reconsider the high level design.

Comment: @brett there is also named operators.  `a *robust* b` and `a *robust*= b`.  But that is utter insanity.

Comment: This `GL0` component provides 3,4-Vector and Matrix operations to support GL requirements. Trying to augment it as something fit for numerical analysis was a failed experiment. I'll provide robust 3,4-inner product functions, and any other requirements can be built from that as needed. Thanks for your ideas - your other answers show a depth of knowledge of C++ arcana in corners I'm still scared of:)